# bank account error google checkout

Tags: android, google-checkout

I added my dev account to my personal email and i want to change it to my company email...how to do this?
Second: 
I used google checkout when first released and added scottrade account to google checkout. I let it go and never verified. No account is closed and I tried to verify but I'm now locked out of bank verification. I cannot add new bank account or move dev account to work account.

Please help because google will not.

Ed

Answer (score 0):

If you signed up for Google Checkout with a Gmail address, you cannot change your login email address.

If you signed up for Google Checkout with an address that doesn't end in @gmail.com, see this article:

https://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?answer=134440

Additionally, you can add varioous contact email addresses:

https://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?answer=63488